# Why applying counting in probability question doesn't work?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've a question with answer like this:

[image: The question]

However, when I tried to solve it using counting, it gets the wrong answer. And I don't know what did I miss so the counting doesn't work. I detailed my work below:

First, get the sample space as the denominator for the probability, which is $(20\cdot 20) + (20\cdot 4) = 480$, where I either throw the 20-sided dice twice or once if I get >10 on my first throw.

To get the numerator of the probability, I count all the possible outcome. Below I use (x,y) to indicate the value I get for my first and second throw respectively.
The possible outcomes:

(1,13) 
(2,12) 
(3,11) 
(4,10) 
(5,9) 
(6,8) 
(7,7)

(13,1) 
(12,2) 
(11,3)

Thus, totally 10 possible outcomes, the numerator is 10.

Thus, the probability = 10/480, but this is wrong.

Please educate me. Numerous times I find applying counting to probability simply doesn't work. And I wonder why. The example above is just one instance I got wrong many times for this kind of question. Would appreciate indicating where did I get wrong conceptually between counting and accounting for probabilities. Thanks.

Comment: not all of the outcomes you listed are equally likely

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that, on each roll of the 20-sided die, each of the 20 outcomes is equally likely? And what about the 4-sided die? And why distract us with a different problem that is not your problem?

Comment: The answer in the image is similarly dubious.  Where did you get that proposed solution in the image?

Comment: Where are outcomes like $(8,6)$ listed? This is a different outcome than $(6,8)$ and should be listed as well. I believe you are missing that, along with $(9,5)$ and $(10,4)$.

But as noted in earlier comments, the answer in the image does not seem correct either, both you and I have noted outcomes that give the desired result of 14, but aren't listed.

Comment: Also, the way you calculate your denominator is wrong. When you roll the 20-sided die twice, it **must** be that the first roll was a 10 or under. So, there are actually $10\cdot 20 = 200$ ways to roll the 20-sided die twice. Similarly there are $10\cdot 4 = 40$ ways to roll the 20-sided die once and the 4 sided die afterwards. So our total is $240$ different ways.

Comment: @DanAsimov 1) Yes of course, as usual in the absence of an exceptional hypothesis 2) idem 3) what "different problem"?

Comment: $20 \times 20 + 20 \times 4 = 480$, it is exact, but I hope you will not use this 480 in your result ... and you use it : not all of the outcomes you listed have same probability to occur.  The formula P= (nb  favorable outcomes)/(nb total outcomes) is valid only when all total outcomes have same probability to occur.